# Flutter : How to set dynamic color in CustomPainter object

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Setting paint color dynamically for CustomPainter's constructor not working.

lines_painter.dart

```
class LinesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double lineHeight = 8;
  final int maxLines = 60;
  final Color customColor;

  LinesPainter(this.customColor);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.save();
    final Paint linePainter = Paint()
      ..color = customColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.5;
    final radius = size.width / 2;

    List.generate(maxLines, (i) {
      var newRadius = (i % 5 == 0) ? radius - 15 : radius - 5;
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, radius), Offset(0, newRadius), linePainter);
      canvas.rotate(2 * pi / maxLines);
    });

    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

utils.dart

```
class Utils{

  List<Color> getColorsArray (){
    return [
      Color(0xff5733),
      Color(0xc70039),
      Color(0x900c3e),
      Color(0x571845),
      Color(0x251e3e),
      Color(0x051e3e),

    ];
  }
}
```

Below code should paint Round shape with lines

```
LinesPainter(Utils().getColorsArray()[0])
```

Expected result:

[image]

Current result:

[image]

Comment: add `print(customColor)` inside `paint()` method, what do you see?

Comment: print(customColor)  
//OutPut 
I/flutter ( 4320): Color(0x00ff5733)

Comment: so you need `Color(0xffff5733)` - and the same with other colors in the array

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: see [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.html)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned in comments I have read the documentation and i got the idea that I am missing the Alpha value in hex code.

Make a change in utils.dart file like below and it works fine for me.

```
class Utils{

  List<Color> getColorsArray (){
    return [
      Color(0xffff5733),
      Color(0xffc70039),
      Color(0xff900c3e),
      Color(0xff571845),
      Color(0xff251e3e),
      Color(0xff051e3e),

    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Well....this was the first ```aaaahaaaa``` thing that I've got when I've started using flutter. :)). Also fyi, Colorr class has 2 nice methods. ```withOpacity``` and ```withAlpha``` you should check those too